# Define a function parameter as a "var" in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have a function like this:

```
private def add[T](n: String, t: T, k: Map[String,T]): T = { k += (n -> t); t }
```

the compiler complains that there is a reassignment to val, so short of changing this to a mutable map, is there a way to say something like "var k: Map..." as in a case class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're asking for is a [*pass by reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) argument.  The JVM doesn't have those and neither does Scala.*

You will either have to return the updated map:

```
private def add[T](n: String, t: T, k: Map[String,T]): Map[String,T] = k + (n -> t)
```

or return both, or if you must return `T`, write a wrapper class:

```
case class Vary[A](var value: A) { def apply() = value }
private def add[T](n: String, t: T, k: Vary[Map[String,T]]) = { k.value += (n -> t); t }

val map = Vary( Map.empty[String,Int] )
add("fish", 5, map)
map()  //Map[String,Int] = Map(fish -> 5)
```

---

*Well, not directly.  Of course, one must change vars in an outer context somehow with closures, and in fact what Scala does is use a wrapper class much like the one I show above.

Comment: It need not be a pass by reference. It could be a `var` without ever making reassignment visibles on the callee. I'll grant you that it does look like he wants pass by reference, as, otherwise, the code would be meaningless. What can I say? I'm picky. :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - The optimization step of my post compilation routine eliminated that branch as dead code and thus I did not mention it. :)